# Add secret username & password to Soap API call in Data Factory

Tags: sql, sql-server, soap, azure-data-factory

I am getting data from Soap API with security (username, password and additional parameters) call with Azure Data Factory using the Copy Data Activity approach (HTTP Linked Service / XML Dataset, etc.). Also I am able to populate SQL Server tables.

However, for security reasons, I need to hide username and password in Copy Data Activity in Data Factory, parameters that I provide in order to connect to Soap API.

I have created a username and password secrets and attempted to substitute it in username and password parameters. It seems I am not able to connect with the service, I get this error:

[image]

Does any of you know if this is possible to achieve? I know Soap API could be a kind of old technology but I would like to know if this is possible to achieve or not. Maybe I am missing something in the middle. I will appreciate your thoughts.

As additional information let me share an image of the parameters I provide in SoapUI in order to connect to Soap API.

arg0 is username, arg1 is password.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can recommend to you to use Azure Key Vault, but it does not answer all your requirements.
You can retrieve your password but you can't retrieve your username from a linked service in azure data factory, its a design limitation.
i highly recommend saving your password in azure key vault since its highly secured.

please read more about it in Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. After that reading I got this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities. So I followed the steps in the documentation: Use Azure Key Vault secrets in pipeline activities.